# FlashPolicy File Server cannot work with node

Tags: node.js, flash, websocket, fallback

I try to use  [FlashPolicy File Server](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/FlashPolicyFileServer) along with node js 0.10.12 and cannot get it to work.

I want to use  FlashPolicy File Server in order to provide websockets fallbacking using [web-sockets-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) (web-sockets-js require FlashPolicy)

In my node right now I use only the http, websockets and pg modules.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
"use strict";
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var pg = require('pg');


var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(clientHtml);
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8000');
});

var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  return true;
}


var pf = require('policyfile').createServer();
pf.listen(8000, server, function(){
  console.log(':3 yay')
});


wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      request.reject(); 
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }
```

In the console I get

```
FlashPolicyFileServer received an error event

listen EADDRINUSE
```

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Server settings is not my strong suit

Thanks in advance

Comment: So far, are you sure that there is no another running instance of app, or smth another uses this port?

Comment: @PavelVelikiy My http server, in node, uses this port. See the line `server.listen(8000, function() {`. Then , the websocket server is based on that http server. How can I add the Flash Policy Server to that system?

Comment: Sorry, of course you can't run your flashpolicyserver on the same port as app, you can just skip this argument and run it as pf.listen(server, function(){
  console.log(':3 yay') 
}); It will use :843 by default, as said in documentation

Comment: @PavelVelikiy Aha! Yes, you are right. Thanks . I get no errors now. The one thing left to do is test it in older browsers and see if something is wrong. And I will let you know..